# Not able to read complete data from serial port in python

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

i am reading cat /proc/kmsg continuously in a loop through serial port.When the no.of bytes  in serial buffer is zero ,i am breaking the loop.

But i am not able to read complete data from the buffer.Some data is missing.How 
can i read complete data without any loss??

```
    import serial
    ser1=serial.Serial('COM67')
    ser.baudrate=115200
    resp=[]
    ser1.write("cat /proc/kmsg\n")   
    cnt=0
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        bytesToRead = ser1.inWaiting()
        c=ser1.read(bytesToRead)
        ser1.flushInput()
        import re
        c=re.sub(r'\x08','',c)
        resp.append(c)            
        if(bytesToRead==0):
            cnt=cnt+1
            if(cnt>5):
                print "-"*57
                ser1.write("\x03")        #'\x03' ==CTRL+C
                break
    ser1.flushInput()
    print "_kmsg data :",resp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in these three lines:

```
bytesToRead = ser1.inWaiting()
c=ser1.read(bytesToRead)
ser1.flushInput()
```

After Python has read how many bytes there are in the input buffer, more can actually be written to it before Python reaches the `flushInput()`. All the bytes that arrive in this duration will not read, but only discarded.

Comment: @peterson.i tried by commenting the flushInput() but still some data is missing.